# Julia-lang comparison of expression and commutativity

Tags: operators, expression, julia, commutativity

OK my title isn't great but it's easily explainable with an example.

```
julia>a = :(1 + 2)
julia>b = :(2 + 1)

julia>a == b
false
```

I have two expressions a and b. I would like to know if they will give me the same results **without being evaluated**.

I though that commutative operators like + or * could infer that the results would be the same.

EDIT: 
Another way to understand it is to compare a very specific subset of expressions that can infer the commutativity of the function:
Expr(:call, +, a, b) <=> Expr(:call, +, b, a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write a fairly simple function to check if two arrays have the same elements, modulo ordering:

```
function eq_modulo_ordering!(xs, ys)  # note !, mutates xs and ys
    while !isempty(xs)
        i = findfirst(isequal(pop!(xs)), ys)
        i === nothing && return false
        deleteat!(ys, i)
    end
    isempty(ys)
end
eq_modulo_ordering(xs, ys) = eq_modulo_ordering!(copy(xs), copy(ys))
```

We can use then use this function to check if two *top-level* expressions are equivalent.

```
function expr_equiv(a::Expr, b::Expr, comm)
    a.head === b.head || return false
    a.head === :call || return a == b
    a.args[1] ∈ comm || return a == b

    eq_modulo_ordering(a.args, b.args)

end
expr_equiv(a, b, comm) = a == b
expr_equiv(a, b) = expr_equiv(a, b, [:+])
```

In the case that we want to check that two expressions are fully equivalent beyond the top-level, we could modify our functions to use mutual recursion to check if the subexpressions are `expr_equiv`, rather than `isequal`.

```
function eq_modulo_ordering!(xs, ys, comm)  # note !, mutates xs and ys
    while !isempty(xs)
        x = pop!(xs)
        i = findfirst(b -> expr_equiv(x, b, comm), ys)
        i === nothing && return false
        deleteat!(ys, i)
    end
    isempty(ys)
end
eq_modulo_ordering(xs, ys, comm) = eq_modulo_ordering!(copy(xs), copy(ys), comm)

function expr_equiv(a::Expr, b::Expr, comm)
    a.head === b.head || return false
    a.head === :call || return a == b
    a.args[1] ∈ comm || return all(expr_equiv.(a.args, b.args, Ref(comm)))

    eq_modulo_ordering(a.args, b.args, comm)
end
expr_equiv(a, b, comm) = a == b
expr_equiv(a, b) = expr_equiv(a, b, [:+])
```

We can now use `expr_equiv` as expected, optionally supplying a list of functions which are commutative.

```
julia> expr_equiv(:((a + b + b) * c), :((b + a + b) * c))
true

julia> expr_equiv(:((a + a + b) * c), :((b + a + b) * c))
false

julia> expr_equiv(:(c * (a + b + b)), :((b + a + b) * c), [:+, :*])
true
```

Comment: I'm very impressed by your answer! I googled some of the functions you've use. 
I'm still struggling with this line "expr_equiv(a, b, comm) = a == b". Can you explain what it does ?

Comment: @ThomasJalabert If the provided objects `a` and `b` are both of type `Expr`, the first method of `expr_equiv` will be called, using our specialized equivalence checking. However, if we one or both are not `Expr`s, we simply want to compare the objects verbatim. For example, for checking `:c` vs `:c` under commutativity, we only care that `:c == :c`.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible. Figuring out whether two programs have the same result without evaluating them is called the *Function Problem* and is provably equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

It is not possible to compute whether to pieces of code will have the same result.

Comment: Actually, I might be wrong, and it is equivalent to Rice's Theorem, not the Halting Problem. It makes no practical difference, though: impossible is impossible regardless of whether it is due to Mr. Turing or Mr. Rice.

Comment: I thought for expressions like that, Julia could know the propriety of the + function. Infering the commutativity is not an impossible task. Just that Expr(:call, +, a, b) <=> Expr(:call, +, b, a)

Comment: @ThomasJalabert `+` is a generic function and is not necessarily commutative in Julia without knowing the actual type of `a` and `b`, so `Expr(:call, +, a, b) <=> Expr(:call, +, b, a)` may or may not be true.

Comment: @张实唯 It's true for the type `Number` and all its sub-types (`Float`, `Int64`...). I gess checking if `a` or `b` is a `Number` is too much time consuming...